# symfony2 formbuilder

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

i created a customFormtype in symfony2 and i'm using it in a formbuilder in my controller.
This is the html result when i render the form:

```
        <div id="form">
              <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="2e8fe0d777b5c0d7d30d9bfd9d5143811c790b1d">
              <div>
                 <label class=" required">Stars</label>
                 <!-- some other stuff -->
              </div>
        </div>
```

Where does the id **form** came from and where can i change the name?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It is described in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming).

Comment: i can't find the sentence where i can set the id. To override the template is not that what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id of the form is defined by the getName() function

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('task');
        $builder->add('dueDate', null, array('widget' => 'single_text'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'task';
    }
}
```

Ex. 'task' here. (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes)

Comment: No, my name is "areaSelect", not "form".

Comment: Update your question with your template code, controller action and form if you want that i see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a named form builder:

```
protected function createMyForm()
{
    return $this->container->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('my_form_name', 'form')
        ->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->getForm();
}
```